# Upload image to folder with NextJS api route and isomorphic-unfetch

Tags: node.js, api, routes, next.js

I'm trying to figure out how I can upload images with NextJS api routes and isomorphic-unfetch. Everything I've seen is utilizing express, but I feel like I should be able to accomplish it with api routes.

So far I have an input of type file that fires an onClick handler:

```
    const handleImage = async (theImg) => {
        try {
            const res = await fetch("/api/admin", {
                method: "POST",
                body: theImg,
            });
            const json = await res.json();
            console.log(json);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };
return(
    <input
        onChange={(e) => handleImage(e.target.files[0])}
        type="file"
        name="uploaded_img"
        placeholder="Upload File"
    />
);
```

but when I try to read the request in the API route, the body appears to be corrupt, and I can't open the resulting file.

api route:

```
import fs from "fs";

export default async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const data = fs.writeFile("./uploads/test.jpg", req.body);
        //file written successfully
        console.log("wrote file");
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
};
```

the resulting file cannot be opened and contains a bunch of missing characters. I'm probably doing this entirely wrong, but any push in the right direction would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: you need to pass your image usning multipart/form-data to your API server.if you are using node.js as an API server you need to check multer for file handling

Comment: you checkout the example in formidable-serverless. that is what you need on nextJS because it's Serverless.